# Show that $(\log n)^{\log n}\in\Omega (n)$

Tags: asymptotics

Show that $(\log n)^{\log n}\in\Omega (n)$

Proceeding with a common logarithm property, we get $$(\log n)^{\log n}=(n^{\log\log n})$$

How do I deduce that $$(n^{\log\log n})\in\Omega(n)$$

If I say that $n=b^{b}$ where $b$ is the base of the logarithm then it can be true, but doesn't it defeat the purpose of it being linear?

Here, $\Omega,\Theta,\mathcal{O}$ are the well known asymptotics, i.e. lower bound, upper bound and the *big O*.

---

This was found in [MIT 6.006 Spring 2020](https://learning-modules.mit.edu/service/materials/groups/276921/files/92c5c4c6-dcb3-4f49-a346-5f7ea916e1e7/link?errorRedirect=%2Fmaterials%2Findex.html), question number 6 although they assumed a base $2$ logarithm.

Comment: closely related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3616406/811225) , [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176235/811225)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n$ is sufficiently large, $\log \log n \geq 1$.  Therefore $n^{\log \log n} \geq n^1 = n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.